# Ubuntu GNOME vs Ubuntu "normal" with gnome

Tags: gnome

So, I know there is the Ubuntu GNOME distro.

And then there is Ubuntu, where I can add (and hence use) gnome.
What's the difference between those two?

For example, we know that Canonical patches certain Gnome packages to "fit" Unity. Does the Ubuntu Gnome distribution (without Unity) include the Canonical modifications or is it pure Gnome?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu GNOME edition will give you an experience which resembles more the vanilla GNOME 3 installation. By installing "normal" Ubuntu you'll get Unity, and if you install GNOME on top of that, you'll end up with all traditional GNOME apps as well as "Unity apps". You'll have more applications (some of which are even going to be redundant), but the option to choose between Unity and GNOME-shell before login.

Comment: I have bad experience with installing Gnome over Unity.

Comment: @umpirsky, my experience with using one Ubuntu flavor on top of another has also not been stellar. I'd rather keep each one in their own partition.

Comment: I really don't know what to do. On one hand I like unity, but really hate the dash.

Comment: give back the choice to the people, and enclosing the liberty to change things is for me too lazy, I'd rather spend time on making flavors on top of others more stable. Windows is doing the same thing by removing the legacy config panel, in the name of UI